# How do i keep PHP from deleting my html form

Tags: php, html, forms, reset

It's my first actual project, but I'm struggeling on this for a whole day now.

I have a number of forms, whose arguments are passed to a shell_exec, which in return delivers a PNG to stdout that plopps up below the form after pressing submit:

```
$im = shell_exec("rrdtool graph '-' $flags $defline $graphline");
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($im).'" />';
};
```

And it actually works. But after hitting "Submit", all forms are empty. I guess because the page is rendered again including the image?
Can I prevent that?

Comment: could we see most of you form code ?

Comment: If "shell_exec" is another PHP file, it will get all the data fields. Save them to $_SESSION variables, and restore them in the first page.

Comment: it's all the same page. shell_exec is running a C program. i'm initializing the variables before with $variable = $_POST['variable'];

Comment: Oh: and when you click "back" in the browser, the content of the forms is back (but the image gone, obviously).